# Mongo db - Querying documents using nested field (nested array and objects)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  "_id":"12345",
  "model":{
     "T":0,
     "serviceTask":[
        {
          "_id":"6789",
           "obj":{
             "params" :{
                "action": "getEmployeeData",
                "employeeId":"123"
             },
             "url":"www.test.com",
             "var":"test",
           },
           "opp":100
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

I have similar structured documents in my collection. How do I query the documents that match action value to `"getEmployeeData"`. I tried dot notation with `$elemMatch`but couldn't get the results.

Comment: Refer Mongo Documentation for the same: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/ & https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Answer (score 2):

Dot notation works fine here, it will return the document if `serviceTask` contains at least one `action` set to `getEmployeeData`

```
db.collection.find({
    "model.serviceTask.obj.params.action": "getEmployeeData"
})
```